# S3 upload using server-side encryption (python SDK)

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-s3

I'm using the following snippet to upload my files to the AWS S3 buckets:

```
import boto3

def upload_to_s3(bucket_name, local_name, name):
    bucket = boto3.resource('s3').Bucket(my_bucket_name)
    bucket.upload_file(local_name, name)
```

Is there any way to modify this code to enable SSE?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are 2 ways.

1. use this: https://www.justdocloud.com/2018/09/21/upload-download-s3-using-aws-kms-python/

   ```python
   s3_client.upload_file(filename, bucketname, objectkey, ExtraArgs={"ServerSideEncryption": "aws:kms", "SSEKMSKeyId": })
   ```
2. Enable Default bucket encryption with KMS on bucket and make sure the user/role you're using to upload has KMS permission, this way you don't need to define any kms key here.

Comment: Thanks, it worked, but I had to specify "AES256" instead of "aws:kms".

Comment: Where's the key ID value...looking to make sure it is an arn. Your solution forces default S3 KMS key as per: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectPUT.html